# D&D 5e, Magic Initiate Feat as a Fighter

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm making a Fighter with a splash of Druid, and sacrificing a feat for Shillelagh, *Produce Flame* and Faire Fire.

HOWEVER! In the description of *Produce Flame*, it says, as your character gains in levels, you get additional d8 for its damage rolls.

The wording is specific about the fact that it's your characters level, not spellcasting level.

Is this the case??

Having Shillelagh as a Fighter, being able to turn wooden weapons into a d8 magical weapon, added with my Extra Attacks, will give me a maximum, 4d8 damage potential when taking the Attack Action. With *Produce Flame* under the same level condition and interpretation of the wording in the spells description, I would also have a similar ranged attack, which at maximum, (I believe is range 30?), and does 4d8 damage.

**TLDR** ; Is this the case for *Produce Flame*? The damage scales off of your characters level and not your spellcasting level?

Most of the specifications between casting spells and your spellcasting level, that i've read, are focused around spell slots. But being that *Produce Flame* is a cantrip, a level 0 spell, you never have to use a spellslot to cast it, in fact you can cast it as many times as you like, just like Shillelagh, despite your pure classes affinity for spells.